# Function Based View to Class Based View

Tags: python, django

How would I convert my Function Based View into Class Based View.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [         
     path('', views.SlideShowView, name="slideshow"),
]
```

models.py

```
class Carousel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="showcase/%y/%m/%d/", blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def SlideShowView(request):
    carousel = Carousel.objects.all()
    context  = {
        'carousel' : carousel,
    }
    return render(request, "showcase.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly covered by a [**`ListView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview):

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class SlideShowView(ListView):
    model = Carousel
    context_object_name = 'carousel'
    template_name = 'showcase.html'
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm pretty new to Django this helped out alot.